# What is the best way to write data to disk to read from it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, dump

Yesterday I did many experiments with data writing to file and then read them from it. I experienced many difficulties with this simple task.
At first I thought, that I can simply save data to a file as is. For example - save list to `file.txt` and then read it back to some variable as list.
I found solution on StackOverflow and I think it is a simplest way to read a list from `file.txt`

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    list_variable = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

So, as a newbie in programming, I would like to know from much more experienced coders - what is the best way to save data to disk for future import?

I personally using stings, dictionaries, lists and tuples. Is there accurate and simple way to work with? (txt, csv, json ... etc.)?

Comment: It really depends on what you’re storing and what you need to do with it. JSON is a nice, simple choice for many purposes, though.

Comment: Different formats have different trade offs.

Comment: @Ryan for example I'm working with lists in list. So I need to iterate items in lists inside list. Some information from other StackOverflow pages said that JSON is the best way to store dictionaries. I tried to work with JSON and is pretty good for my needs (in case of dictionaries). Is it a good idea to store lists data on local SSD using standard JSON module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of writing / reading from / to files is that you need to serialize your data (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)).

In order to retrieve your data and restore it as a data structure of your choice (i.e. tuples, lists or w/e) you need a way to *de-*serialize the data you read. That can be achieved by [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the input stream of data.

As a solution to your matter, you can use the `json` package by importing it and use `json.dumps(...)` and `json.loads(...)` to respectively write and read JSON formatted data.